# JavaScript: count minimal length of characters in text, ignoring special codes inside

Tags: javascript, count, special-characters

I want to ignore counting the length of characters in the text if there are special codes inside in textarea. I mean not to count the special codes characters in the text. I use special codes to define inputing smileys in the text. I want to count only the length of the text ignoring special code.

Here is my approximate code I tried to write, but can't let it work:

```
// smileys
// =======

function smileys(){

var smile = new Array();

smile[0]  = "[:rolleyes:]";
smile[1]  = "[:D]";
smile[2]  = "[:blink:]";
smile[3]  = "[:unsure:]";
smile[4]  = "[8)]";
smile[5]  = "[:-x]";

return(smile);
}

// symbols length limitation
// =========================

function minSymbols(field){

var get_smile = smileys();
var text = field.value;

for(var i=0; i<get_smile.length; i++){
for(var j=0; j<(text.length); j++){
if(get_smile[i]==text[j]){
text = field.value.replace(get_smile[i],"");
}
}
}

if(text.length < 50){
document.getElementById("saveB").disabled=true;
} else {
document.getElementById("saveB").disabled=false;
}
}
```

How the script should be in order to let it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function minSymbols(field){
    var get_smile = smileys();
    var text = field.value;

    for(var i=0; i<get_smile.length; i++){
        text = text.replace(get_smile[i],"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ivo Sabev! This was the thing I needed! Works perfect! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by changing how I define the smilies:

```
var smilies = [
    {text: "[:rolleyes:]", exp: /\[\:rolleyes\:\]/g},
    {text: "[:D]",         exp: /\[\:D\]/g},
    {text: "[:blink:]",    exp: /\[\:blink\:\]/g},
    {text: "[:unsure:]",   exp: /\[\:unsure\:\]/g},
    {text: "[8)]",         exp: /\[8\)\]/g},
    {text: "[:-x]",        exp: /\[\:-x\]/g}
];
```

(I didn't immediately see any reason this had to be a function, but you can make it one if you want.) That's an array of objects, each object having a `text` property with the smiley text and an `exp` object with a RegExp that would match it (with the global flag set).

Then the function looks a bit like this:

```
function getLengthMinusSmilies(field) {
    var text, index, length, smiley;

    text = field.value;
    length = text.length;
    for (index = 0; index < smilies.length; ++index) {
        smiley = smilies[index];
        while (smiley.exp.test(text)) {
            length -= smiley.text.length;
        }
    }
    return length;
}
```

That avoids creating and throwing away temporary strings. It just counts matches of smilies and disregards their length.

You don't have to use objects with `text` and `exp` values, you can use paralle arrays if you like:

```
var smilies = [
    "[:rolleyes:]",
    "[:D]",
    "[:blink:]",
    "[:unsure:]",
    "[8)]",
    "[:-x]"
];

var matchExps = [
    /\[\:rolleyes\:\]/g,
    /\[\:D\]/g,
    /\[\:blink\:\]/g,
    /\[\:unsure\:\]/g,
    /\[8\)\]/g,
    /\[\:-x\]/g
];
```

...and then adjust the loop in the function accordingly. Using one array with objects tends to be more maintainable, but if you need an array elsewhere...

Comment: T.J. Crowder, your example changes the whole structure of my script. I could use it in other solutions. But therefore thank you at all! ;-)

Comment: @ilnur777: Yeah, it was a bit radical. :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTxtLen()
{
    var str=document.getElementById('myTxtBox').value;

        str=str.replace(/\[:some:\]/g,'');
        str=str.replace(/\[:some2:\]/g,'');

        alert(str.length);
}
```

Comment: Not the thing, I need. Thank you!